# Parent to child using ngFor to pass on click

Tags: angular, angular-components

`load-view.component.ts` is the parent file that has a method

```
    anyData: any;
    pushLoadLocationData(Id: number) {
        this.anyData = Id;
        console.log(Id); //shows data
        this.currentSubjectLocationView.subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.anyData= data.filter(d => d.id === Id)[0].locations;
        });
      }
```

to push data through `anyData` into this page `load-view.component.html` as parent to child
like this `[locationData]="anyData"`

```
<tr *ngFor="let loadData of customerLoadAndLocation;let i = index">
   <td class="td-v-t text-center pt-5">{{i+1}}<br />
      Mile {{i}}<br />
   </td>
   <td class="pl-2 pt-2">
      <b>XYZ Transportation</b>                                                
      <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#StopsDetailspop">
        <i (click)="pushLoadLocationData(loadData.id)">
        </i>
      </a>
      <!-- Modal-->
      <div class="modal fade" id="StopsDetailspop" tabindex="-1"
         role="dialog" aria-labelledby="StopsDetailspop" aria-hidden="true">                                                    
         <app-update-location-of-add-stop [locationData]="anyData"></app-update-location-of-add-stop>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

At the receiving child page is this.

```
@Input() locationData: any;
constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.locationData); // shows undefined
}
```

So the click button `pushLoadLocationData` does not work to send data from parent to child within this `*ngFor` loop as sure it gives **undefined** on child page due to the fact that `locationData` is having no data but on click the data is not able to reach to this child page.

Comment: Please make a reproduceable example https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: are you in onPush env ? 

what about this array customerLoadAndLocation ? how it's defined?  and actually, it's kinda wrong the structure because all your app-update-location-of-add-stop components will be bound to the same "anyData".

Comment: @AriguiAhmed `customerLoadAndLocation` is an array of object but my concern is that I cannot pass data on click to child on ngFor it gives undefined which is correct as `anyData` has no data on parent at present but when on click it should be able to send data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, the problem is, that `anyData` doesn't contain your expected data yet, when the HTML-Template gets rendered.

I'd recommend subscribing to `currentSubjectLocationView` in the HTML-Template by making use of the async pipe:

```
<tr *ngFor="let loadData of customerLoadAndLocation;let i = index">
   <td class="td-v-t text-center pt-5">{{i+1}}<br />
      Mile {{i}}<br />
   </td>
   <td class="pl-2 pt-2">
      <b>XYZ Transportation</b>                                                
      <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#StopsDetailspop">
        <i (click)="pushLoadLocationData(loadData.id)">
        </i>
      </a>
      <!-- Modal-->
      <div *ngIf="locationData$ | async as locationData" class="modal fade" id="StopsDetailspop" tabindex="-1"
         role="dialog" aria-labelledby="StopsDetailspop" aria-hidden="true">                                                    
         <app-update-location-of-add-stop [locationData]="locationData"></app-update-location-of-add-stop>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Your typescript code of `load-view component` would then look like:

```
locationData$: Observable<any>;
pushLoadLocationData(id: number) {
    locationData$ = this.currentSubjectLocationView.pipe(
        filter((x) => x.id === id),
        map((x) => x[0].locations)
    );
}
```

Note that you have to import `Observable`, `filter` and `map` operator from rxjs

Comment: `anyData` data will never render it to child page which I mentioned, I was trying to send data through click to the `anyData` from `pushLoadLocationData` method consider this that I want to push data through click from anchor tag by binding `anyData` which I assume would push to child page

Answer (score 0):

actully the data not ready before click on the i element if you want to get the data based when it ready just you have to follow this approach
you can change the child component input to be setter like this

```typescript
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

// the child component 
// ...


private _clickedData = new Subject<any>();

@Input() set locationData(value: any) {this._clickedData.next(value)}

constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this._clickedData.subscribe((value: any)=>{
      console.log(value) // you will get the data when it changed by clicked from the parent Component 
   })
 }
```

Comment: Tried this as well but data never reached.

Comment: The data is reaching the `pushLoadLocationData` method `console.log(Id);` I can get the data but after assigning like this `this.anyData = Id;` it will never reach the child page.